# What wire size do I need for a 200A residential service?

Tags: electrical-panel

I’m planning on upgrading my electrical service to 200 amps but I’m not sure what aluminum wire size I need. I get confused with the ambient temperature chart, I’m located around Houston Texas area

Comment: Is this for a service lateral/service mast to the meter socket, for the service entrance conductors from your meter to your panel, or a feeder from a meter-main to a subpanel in the house?

Comment: From meter to main electrical panel I don’t have any subpanel

Comment: Do you have a main breaker at the meter?  (it's a 2020 Code requirement and many municipalities required it years before).

Comment: I won't  stake my life on this so it's a comment. The 200 amp service  can be  derated to .83 so that's 166 amps. At 75 degrees C, 3/0 Al is 155 amps and 4/0 Al is good for 180 amps so 4/0 Al with 3/0 AL neutral would be my guess .

Answer (score 2):

If the load is feeding the entire home it can be de rated to 83% as long as the calculated load Is below this 166A  310.15.B.7.1 (& .2)
AND
The ampacity of the feeder can not be below 83% so 4/0 rated at 180 amps is the minimum

The 75 degree table is used. Per NEC 110.14.C.1.b
@Jack had it I provided the code references.

Yes if overhead run some think that table can be used but only if the feed has less than 24” of conduit.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Al size is 4/0. Length of conductors could need larger. Ambient temp would be subject to actual installation and local amendments.

You're probably confused because the NEC keeps changing the way we get to the same answer. We used to have a Table, 310.15(B)(7). Then 2014 they took a way the table and said:

> 310.15(B)(7)(1) For a service rated 100 through 400 A, the service conductors supplying the entire load associated with a one-family
> dwelling, or the service conductors supplying the entire load
> associated with an individual dwelling unit in a two-family or
> multifamily dwelling, shall be permitted to have an ampacity not less
> than 83 percent of the service rating.

So then 83% of 200, Table 310.16/310.15(B)(16), 75°C conductor rating, same size as the old table.

Now 2020, Meet the new boss, same as the old boss.

NEC 310.15(B)(7)(1) moved to 310.12(B), but with new table, 310.12.

[image]

Comment: That table only works for whole services. The reason they got rid of it is people looking for how big a wire for their feeder kept finding this table and improperly using it. (Not least, it is easier to understand than the proper table, 310.15(B)(16).